Node.js returns to different REACT page view
Using REACT and node.js.
Node.js connects and updates a JSON file.
When I return back from the backend file I do not return to where I was previously.
Instead a complete refresh of the webpage occurs so I end up at the start again.
Is the answer to create sessionStorage to track where I am? Quite lost of what to do.
I start with app.js and have a useState() to track what page view I want to see.
{const [currentView, setCurrentView] = useState('home'); // Default View}
As you can see the default value is 'home'. Later in the code there is an 'admin' button option to bring the admin section into view
{ <button onClick={() => 
  setCurrentView('admin')} className="big-btn" aria-label="Go to Admin 
  Section">Admin</button>}

Which is connected to this portion of code to show the contents of the Admin.js file
{{/* Admin View */}
  <div className={`mainViewContainer ${currentView === 'admin' ? 'active' : ''}`}>
    <div id="adminViewContainer">
      <Admin backButton={
        <button 
          onClick={() => setCurrentView('home')} 
          className="mainBackBtn" 
          aria-label="Go back to Home">← Back
        </button>
      }/>
    </div>  
  </div>}

All works well and the admin screen is seen allowing me to add certain information into the input fields. Hitting the submit button grabs the information I added and sends that data as a "POST" event to the the backend file called server.js.
That JSON file is updated correctly from server.js. However what is funny is what happens after that. I do return initially to the admin.js script as I can see my table update with the new information.
Then I flip back to the initial 'home' screen. I can see that it is a complete refresh as all my previous console logs, to track what is happening, disappears. The initial console log statements on starting app.js then appears.
I can resolved the problem by removing the connection to server.js and just use the useState() associated with updating the input fields, to update the table in the admin section. But of course the JSON file is not updated.
Someone has already posted that I should explore preventDefault() which I implemented but the problem still exists as I tried this updated form submission on Google Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Form is as follows
{ <form id="adminFormContainer" onSubmit={(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();  // Prevent page refresh
  handleSubmit();      // Call your handleSubmit function
  }}>
<div id="adminNameClubContainer">
  <div id="adminNameAvailabilityContainer">
    <input 
      type="text" 
      value={firstName} 
      onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)} 
      placeholder="First Name" 
    />
    <input 
      type="text" 
      value={lastName} 
      onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)} 
      placeholder="Last Name" 
    />
   
  </div>
</div>

<div id="addNewPlayerBtnContainer">
  <button type="button" className="resetPlayerBtn" onClick= 
  {resetFields}>Reset</button>
  <button type="submit" id="adminSubmitBtn">Accept</button> 
  {/* Submit button */}
</div>
  </form>}

I wonder whether it has something to so with the function that sends the data to the backend? Is the preventDefault() being negated by calling my function?
 {const handleSubmit = () => {
try {
  console.log('\nStarting the process to add or update a 
  player...');
  }

Any advice is gratefully received and I also appreciate anyone who has taken the time to read this.


Hitting the submit button grabs the information..

Some browser events have default behavior associated with them. For example, a  submit event, which happens when a button inside of it is clicked, will reload the whole page by default. Please see below a sample code and test run observation.
App.js
export default function Signup() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={() => alert('Submitting!')}>
      <input />
      <button>Send</button>
    </form>
  );
}

Test run & observation:
After hitting the submit button, the text entered will be cleared.
You can call e.preventDefault() on the event object to stop this from happening. The following code prevents it.
App.js
export default function Signup() {
  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Submitting!');
      }}
    >
      <input />
      <button>Send</button>
    </form>
  );
}

Test run & observation:
After hitting the submit button, the text entered will be retained.
You can see the same has been discussed here : Preventing default behavior 

Hi. I looked at what you sent and implemented that code but still the problems exists. First point was that I had not encapsulated my input fields in a form element. Now updated. Then implemented the preventDefault() syntax. Code works as expected except that the webpage still refreshes. Tried it on Google Chrome and Firefox and Opera

Hi, Sorry for providing an insufficient answer. Is it possible to share the source code in Github ? If not possible, please look at the two areas closely. The first one is the what is coded inside "server.js" as you see if it is not called, the issue does not happen. Another point is the "backButton" passed to the Admin component. Please do not pass it and see if the issue persisting or not ?
